# How to correctly respond to HTTP CONNECT in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, https, proxy-server

I am building a Proxy server, upon receiving a HTTP CONNECT request I establish a connection to the destination server and if successful return

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
<<empty line>>
```

In Firefox this results in the opening of a tunnel and data being exchanged, loading and eventually delivered/rendered in the browser

In Google Chrome, I immediately just see:

```
ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
```

As the server appears to be working fine for Firefox but not for Chrome I can only assume that Chrome expects a different response back. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

I found [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=114255) chromium issue here which describes the same symptoms - user gets ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED. I enabled the --log-net-log command line parameter and can see in the log that the ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED error occurs directly after receiving my 200 Connection established proxy response.

Higher up between the request and the response I see a -109 error which corresponds to ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE.

I have included an extract below of what I think the relevant parts of the net-log are:

```
{"params":{"headers":["Host: mail.google.com","Proxy-Connection: keep-alive","User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"],"line":"CONNECT mail.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1\r\n"},"phase":0,"source":{"id":822,"type":5},"time":"331488980","type":125},
{"params":{"headers":["Host: mail.google.com","Proxy-Connection: keep-alive","User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"],"line":"CONNECT mail.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1\r\n"},"phase":0,"source":{"id":822,"type":5},"time":"331488980","type":129},
{"params":{"byte_count":227},"phase":0,"source":{"id":822,"type":5},"time":"331488980","type":61},
{"phase":2,"source":{"id":822,"type":5},"time":"331488981","type":124},
{"phase":1,"source":{"id":822,"type":5},"time":"331488981","type":126},
{"phase":1,"source":{"id":822,"type":5},"time":"331488981","type":207},
{"params":{"address_family":0,"allow_cached_response":true,"host":"mail.google.com:0","is_speculative":false,"source_dependency":{"id":0,"type":0}},"phase":1,"source":{"id":823,"type":8},"time":"331489008","type":4},
{"params":{"source_dependency":{"id":823,"type":8}},"phase":1,"source":{"id":824,"type":21},"time":"331489008","type":299},
{"params":{"source_dependency":{"id":824,"type":21}},"phase":1,"source":{"id":825,"type":14},"time":"331489008","type":34},
{"params":{"address":"[2001:4860:4860::8888]:53"},"phase":1,"source":{"id":825,"type":14},"time":"331489008","type":70},
{"params":{"net_error":-109},"phase":2,"source":{"id":825,"type":14},"time":"331489008","type":70},
{"phase":2,"source":{"id":825,"type":14},"time":"331489008","type":34},
{"phase":2,"source":{"id":824,"type":21},"time":"331489008","type":299},
{"phase":0,"source":{"id":823,"type":8},"time":"331489008","type":6},
{"phase":2,"source":{"id":823,"type":8},"time":"331489008","type":4},
{"params":{"byte_count":74},"phase":0,"source":{"id":822,"type":5},"time":"331489052","type":63},
{"phase":2,"source":{"id":822,"type":5},"time":"331489052","type":207},
{"params":{"headers":["HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established"]},"phase":0,"source":{"id":822,"type":5},"time":"331489052","type":127},
{"params":{"net_error":-111},"phase":2,"source":{"id":822,"type":5},"time":"331489052","type":126},
```

If you need to see more of the log I have posted the whole log [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8JuL0rVSQEKMWxhaC1XYU5hTDg/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Not exactly but I started to re-work my solution which led me to ask this question which got me where I needed to go. Maybe it will help you too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188595/how-to-forward-https-traffic-from-a-socks-proxy-to-http-proxy

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but just run into this issue myself. What happened in my case is that I was sending an extra byte in the CONNECT response. 
Found this by enabling NetLog (in *Everything* capture mode) in Chrome:

```
--> bytes =
  48 54 54 50 2F 31 2E 31  20 32 30 30 20 43 6F 6E   HTTP/1.1 200 Con
  6E 65 63 74 69 6F 6E 20  65 73 74 61 62 6C 69 73   nection establis
  68 65 64 0D 0A 0D 0A 00                            hed....
```

See the trailing 00. Chrome (and curl) seems to be [more strict](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/06bd97455ddc38d0cd63bc098fa5bf2aab4fd79e/net/http/http_proxy_client_socket.cc#L448) than Firefox or Safari in that the whole buffer you send it needs to be a well formed HTTP response.

I suggest you [capture a full NetLog dump](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/providing-network-details) and look at the bytes that Chrome is receiving.