# How to forward HTTPS traffic from a SOCKS proxy to HTTP proxy

Tags: sockets, http, network-programming, network-protocols, socks

I have written a SOCKS proxy which works with both HTTP and HTTPS traffic if chaining is turned off.

If chaining is turned on and the forwarding host and port belong to a filtering HTTP proxy then only HTTP traffic can flow. HTTPS traffic does not flow and reports an SSL error.

Note that the HTTP proxy does handle HTTPS traffic when the request is coming direct from the browser and not from the SOCKS server.

As an example if I make a request to https://www.google.com the following occurs:

1) Client sends a SOCKS 5 greeting to let us know which auth methods are acceptable.

2) Server responds with NO_AUTH

3) Client sends a connection request (which includes the intended destination host and port).

4) The server creates and connects a socket to the HTTP proxy server and responds to the client with GRANTED

5) The SOCKS server then receives the following request (the invisible/control characters have all been replaced with their character codes so you can see what's going on):

```
\u0016\u0003\u0001\u0000Ñ\u0001\u0000\u0000Í\u0003\u0003áp¥@Ia¹\u0001„Ä\u0006 É;š‰‰4\u001dýà•J>Ü6¢Þ\fö\u001c%\u0000\u0000(À+À/\u0000žÌ\u0014Ì\u0013À\nÀ\tÀ\u0013À\u0014À\u0007À\u0011\u00003\u00002\u00009\u0000œ\u0000/\u00005\u0000\n\u0000\u0005\u0000\u0004\u0001\u0000\u0000|\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0013\u0000\u0011\u0000\u0000\u000ewww.google.comÿ\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000\n\u0000\b\u0000\u0006\u0000\u0017\u0000\u0018\u0000\u0019\u0000\u000b\u0000\u0002\u0001\u0000\u0000#\u0000\u00003t\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0010\u0000\u001b\u0000\u0019\u0006spdy/3\bspdy/3.1\bhttp/1.1uP\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0005\u0000\u0005\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0012\u0000\u0000\u0000\r\u0000\u0012\u0000\u0010\u0004\u0001\u0005\u0001\u0002\u0001\u0004\u0003\u0005\u0003\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0002\u0002\u0002
```

As you can see, its completely unreadable, but we already know where the user intends to go from the initial SOCKS connection message (step 3) so we can create and issue the following connect request:

```
CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: MySocksServer\r\nProxy-Connection: keep-alive\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n
```

6) This newly constructed CONNECT is sent to the HTTP proxy that we are chaining to, this proxy checks against its filter rules and responds with:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established\r\nVia: 1.1 HTTPserverName\r\nX-WebMarshal-RequestID: AN_ID_STRING\r\n\r\n
```

7) This is received in our SOCKS server and is forwarded (unmodified) to the client. In my debugging I am monitoring the sockets directly before the send request and can see that the client socket is connected.

8) The next event raised is an error, with the error, SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED, running another check on the sockets confirms that the client socket is indeed no longer connected.

Why would my Socket be getting closed between steps 7 and 8 here? Have I not followed the protocol correctly? I can't see what I am missing. I guess I am handling the CONNECT method wrong in some way?

If I do not modify the request received by the SOCKS server (i.e. convert it into a CONNECT request) and instead forward on the unreadable data direct to the HTTP proxy then the Logs for the HTTP proxy show either:

```
Badly formated request: \u0016\u0003\u001
Bad request received.
```

OR

```
Failed to read request: Client closed connection. (0)
1Request took 0 ms + 23 ms idle time
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 6) This newly constructed CONNECT is sent to the HTTP proxy ... this proxy ... responds with:
>
> 7) This is received in our SOCKS server and is forwarded (unmodified) to the client...

This is wrong. You generate the CONNECT request in your SOCKS proxy and therefore you should keep the response to this request to yourself and not forward it to the client. What you should do:

- If you receive the start of the SSL handshake from the client ("\x16\x03... ") you should buffer it.
- Then you create the CONNECT request and send it to the proxy. The Host header and Proxy-Connection headers have no meaning with CONNECT so you don't need to add them.
- Read the response from the proxy to the CONNECT request. If status code is not 200 something is wrong and you should close the connection to the client. There is no easy way to transfer the error information to the client.
- If status code is 200 forward the buffered ClientHello from the client to the server through the proxy and from then on forward everything between client and server (through the proxy tunnel).

Comment: You don't need to buffer in the first step.  There is nothing to read because the client should not be sending any HTTP(S) or SSL data until the SOCKS connection reports success, which it should not be doing until the HTTP proxy responds first.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: If I understand the problem correctly the SOCKS server should translate HTTP(s) socks requests into HTTP(s) proxy requests. Thus the socks server is the same for HTTP and HTTPS and you have to distinguish by the initial bytes of the connection if it will be plain HTTP (e.g. GET, POST...) or HTTPS ("\x16\x03..."), because the you need to handle these cases differently.

Comment: You understand incorrectly.  The SOCKS proxy does not need to handle them different.  It doesn't even need to look at the HTTP(S) data at all. See my answer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I don't think (yet) I understood it wrong. Browsers don't let you configure different socks proxies for http and https, so the socks proxy itself must detect the protocol, because http and https needs to be handled differently (see comment at your response).

Comment: SOCKS works the same way regardless of the protocol passing through it. SOCKS does not care. That is why browsers and other client apps do not provide separate proxy settings for HTTP and HTTPS.  HTTP and HTTPS *do not* need to be handled differently in SOCKS. *IF* the SOCKS proxy needs to differentiate, such as when chaining to another proxy that is known to implement HTTP and HTTPS differently, the difference is handled transparently on the SOCKS end, the client does not need to know, and *does not* need separate proxy settings for HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: Exactly. And this is why in this case the SOCKS proxy needs to find out if it was HTTP or HTTPS to address the upstream HTTP proxy the correct way, at least if you want/need to handle HTTP as HTTP and not just tunnel it through the proxy like done with HTTPS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58942/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-steffen-ullrich).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich is there an RFC or something "official" that states all SSL handshakes start with "\x16\x03... "?

Comment: All TLS1.x and SSL3.0 handshakes start this way: \x16 is record type handshake (decimal 22) which is then followed by the TLS version, i.e. \x03\x00 for SSL3.0, \x03\x01 for TLS1.0, \x03\x02 for TLS1.1 and \x03\x03 for TLS1.2.

Answer (score 6):

The correct sequence is:

1. client connects to SOCKS proxy, authenticates as needed.
2. client sends a SOCKS connect request to create a tunnel to `www.google.com:443`.
3. SOCKS proxy connects to HTTP proxy
4. SOCKS proxy sends an HTTP `CONNECT` request to create a tunnel to `www.google.com:443`.
5. SOCKS proxy receives a reply from HTTP proxy.
6. SOCKS proxy sends an appropriate SOCKS reply to client.
7. If HTTP proxy was successful, pass unmodified data between client and HTTP proxy until one of them disconnects.
8. close the client connection and the HTTP proxy connection.

When you chain proxies, you have to negotiate the tunnels before you can then start passing application data through them.  Do not send a tunnel reply to the client until the next proxy replies with its tunnel status first.

Comment: This proposal works only if the socks proxy is different for HTTP and HTTPS, because you don't know after step 1 if the request from the client will be HTTPS (needs CONNECT) or GET|POST (needs rewrite of URL in request line). But, browsers let you usually only configure a single socks proxy which gets used for all protocols.

Comment: The SOCKS proxy does not NEED to know whether it is HTTPS or not.  This works equally well for both HTTP and HTTPS.  When the client initiates its SSL handshake, that data needs to be sent as-is to the target HTTPS server directly.  The tunnels don't care whether the data is HTTP or SSL or PNG or anything for that matter, they are merely transparent passthroughs. The client asked the SOCKS proxy to connect to some host/port. Period. The SOCKS proxy asks the HTTP proxy to connect to the same host/port. Period.  And so on, until the host/port is reached (or an error occurs).

Comment: Yes and no. Most proxies ignore the content of the tunnel and your solution works with these. But proxies on firewalls often do SSL inspection and will not let non-SSL traffic pass through the tunnel. In these cases you need to have a real http proxy instead of just using a tunnel for everything. And then you need to detect the protocol and handle http and https differently.

Comment: But until the SOCKS proxy replies back to the client with success to the client's connect request, the client will not send its SSL handshake, so there is nothing for the SOCKS proxy to inspect. The client should not be sending anything until the SOCKS proxy says the tunnel has been established first. So what you say would only work if the SOCKS proxy replies to the client before getting the HTTP proxy reply.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The socks server must accept the connection before it gets the necessary data to determine the application protocol. But this seems to be the case in the initial question (step 4).

Comment: From what I'm reading in your comments I think I am maybe doing things in the wrong order. I need to issue the HTTP CONNECT before I return the GRANTED message in my step 4? Currently I am doing it afterwards.

Comment: @John: in many scenarios, yes.  Don't send GRANTED back to the client unless the HTTP `CONNECT` is successful first. What Steffen describes is a less common scenario that requires the GRANTED first so that the client's subsequent data can be inspected in order to decide what the next step should be based on the type of data the client is sending.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, don't I only need to issue the CONNECT if I have HTTPS traffic? HTTP can just be forwarded as/is, well thats how it works currently.

Comment: The SOCKS proxy could certainly connect to the target HTTP server directly for non-HTTPS traffic. But then, it could also connect directly for HTTPS traffic as well, and HTTPS would work fine. The whole point of this exercise seems to be chaining proxies together for both HTTP and HTTPS traffic.  HTTP vs HTTPS does not change how `CONNECT` works, and it works fine for both. However HTTP proxies do not require `CONNECT` for HTTP traffic, only for HTTPS traffic, but you don't have to differentiate if you don't want to, you can use `CONNECT` for both.

Comment: Using full URLs in GET/POST requests through an HTTP proxy is useful only if the HTTP proxy is also acting as an HTTP cache proxy.